# Summing the numbers in a list except for the first even number in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am tryin to write a function that sums all of the numbers except for the first even number on the list. a break function came into my mind for exiting the loop when encountered with the first even number but i couldn't managed to build it. i need help. thanks.

for example:

numbers = [4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
totsum must be 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 40 (skipped the first even number '4')

here is my incomplete code:

```
nmbrs = [4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]





def totsum_effen(n):
    #sum the total numbers except for the first even number
    while True:
        sum = 0
        for i in nmbrs:
            if i % 2 == 0:

                break

            sum = sum + i


        return (sum)
```

Comment: why pass in `n`? you never use it in your function

Comment: Replace break with continue and you are good to go

Comment: Take the cap off your eyes, maybe you'll find the shift key then and see all your typos. Also, what's the expected result for your example? Not clear.

Comment: ^ you also rest sum in every loop....delcare `sum` outside of the while loop

Comment: @ArpitSolanki it doesn't work since it adds all the even numbers in the list

Comment: @HarryHeller You are saying that "sum the total numbers except for the first even number", but you are doing `i%2==0` that would actually skip all the even numbers!!
Is that what you want to do??
Or just skip the first even number

Answer (score 5):

I'd just sum it all and subtract the first even number (if it exists).

```
>>> numbers = [4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> sum(numbers) - next((x for x in numbers if x % 2 == 0), 0)
40
```

Comment: I love one liners smooth small and precise

Comment: I knew there was a way to do this nicely, good shout using `next()`

Comment: Hmm, this is certainly cleaner. I hadn't an idea next took a default value argument.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is just sum the array and subtract the first even number

```
nmbrs = [4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def totsum_effen(nmbrs):
    #sum the total numbers except for the first even number
    even_nmbrs = [num for num in nmbrs if num % 2 == 0]
    temp_sum = sum(nmbrs)
    if len(even_nmbrs) > 0:
        temp_sum -= even_nmbrs[0]
    return temp_sum
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be really inefficient on a big list of mostly even numbers?

Comment: For sure - I was going for short & sweet but if there's ever a point where you're writing an enterprise program that does this, definitely just iterate over the list until you find the first even number and use that.

Comment: It's a shame, I can't think of a way to do that using a list comprehension. I'm sure one exists though.

Comment: @tom anyway it does not matter if it's inefficient it's not going to be used in production code. Both answers are perfect anyway plus one for both and minus one for OP :)

Comment: Yeah I agree @ArpitSolanki I'm just frustrated that I've not yet seen a super-pythonic one liner for it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
nmbrs = [4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def totsum_effem():
    nmbrs_copy = nmbrs.copy()
    for index, num in enumerate(nmbrs):
        if num % 2 == 0:
            del nmbrs_copy[index]
            break
    return sum(nmbrs_copy)
```

---

```
>>> print(totsum_effem())
40
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another pythonic one liner (python3.x only):

```
In [36]: sum(num) - next(filter(lambda x: not x % 2, num + [0]))
Out[36]: 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will fail to add the odd numbers before the first even number. 
This way you can keep a check and as soon as the first even number occurs skip that and continue with the loop.

```
def totsum_effen(nmbrs):
    flag = 0
    sum = 0
    for i in nmbrs:
        if flag == 0 and i % 2 == 0:
            flag = 1
        else:
            sum += i
    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve can be done more efficiently with more complex code but that requires a deep understanding of Python. I re-write your code in beginner easy to understand Python with explanations for a few mistakes in your code and few things to pay attention to. Let me know if you can understand it.

```
#sum the total numbers except for the first even number  (1)
def totsum_effen(n): #(2)
  sum = 0    #(3)
  ignore_first_even = True   #(4)
  for i in n:
    if(i % 2 == 0 and ignore_first_even):   #(5)
      ignore_first_even = False
      continue
    sum = sum + i
  return (sum)

print(totsum_effen(nmbrs))
```

1. you should place description of your function the line before the function definition block
2. In your code you the parameter `n` was never used. pass in parameter(s) you want to use in the function and refer to those parameters.
3. Usually, you want to declare your variable use for cumulation or totaling *oustide* of for loop or while loop. so it does not get reset every loop.
4. use a flat `ignore_first_even` to ignore the first even number by using `ignore_first_even` in an `if` statment in 4
5. if the number is even and the `ignore_first_even` is true then we set the `ignore_first_even` to false. Notice that `ignore_first_even` can never be set to true again this way we only ignore the first even number. Then we `continue` to the next iteration without adding this number to our `sum`

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, instead of using break, you can try using continue. It simply skips the rest of the code in the loop for the current iteration and jumps to the next iteration.
2. Secondly, use a count variable to check for the first even number in the list.

Please check the following code. It's just an implementation of the things mentioned above.

```
nmbrs = [4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def totsum_effen(nmbrs) :
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    for i in nmbrs :
        if i%2==0 and count==0 :
            count = count + 1
            continue
        sum = sum + i
    return sum
print('Printing the sum of all the numbers in the list except the 1st even number....')
print(totsum_effen(nmbrs))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def totsum_effen(n):
    #sum the total numbers except for the first even number
    sum = 0
    flag = False
    for val in nmbrs:
        if not flag:
          if val % 2 == 0:
            flag = True
          else:
            sum += val
        else:
          sum = sum + val

    return (sum)

nmbrs = [4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```